# Why inference is lost after Pick

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

Consider this:

```
type THandlerArgsBase<TValue> = {
    value: TValue | undefined;
}

type THandlerArgsUnnamed<TValue> = THandlerArgsBase<TValue> & {
    name: undefined;
}

type THandlerArgsNamed<TValue> = THandlerArgsBase<TValue> & {
    name: string;
}



type TProvaBase<TValue> = {
    value?: TValue | undefined;
    foo?: string;
    blah?: number;
}

type TProvaUnnamed<TValue> = TProvaBase<TValue> & {
    name?: undefined;
    handler?: (args: THandlerArgsUnnamed<TValue>) => void;
}

type TProvaNamed<TValue> = TProvaBase<TValue> & {
    name: string;
    handler?: (args: THandlerArgsNamed<TValue>) => void;
}

type TProva<TValue> =
    | TProvaUnnamed<TValue>
    | TProvaNamed<TValue>
    ;


//generic implementation
function prova<TValue>(props: TProva<TValue>): void {
    const {
        value,
        name,
        handler,
    } = props;

    if (handler) {
        typeof name === "string"
            ? handler({ name, value })
            : handler({ name, value })
    }
}


//usage
prova<number>({
    name: "xyz",
    handler: ({ name, value }) => void 0,  //name is string: correct!
})

prova<number>({
    handler: ({ name, value }) => void 0,  //name is undefined: correct!
})


//specialization

type TProvaBool = Pick<TProva<boolean>, "value" | "name" | "handler">;

function prova_bool(props: TProvaBool): void {
    const {
        value,
        name,
        handler,
    } = props;

    if (handler) {
        typeof name === "string"
            ? handler({ name, value })    //compilation error!
            : handler({ name, value })    //compilation error!
    }
}
```

In the latter function, almost everything is inferred correctly, but the `handler` field which is inferred as:

```
handler: (args: never) => void
```

However, if I omit `Pick`-ing the useful field, everything goes fine:

```
type TProvaBool = TProva<boolean>;
```

Just tried in the Typescript playground (v5.0.4).

So, why the inference is lost after `Pick`-ing/specializing the generic function?

Any workaround?

Comment: `Pick<T, K>` doesn't *distribute* over unions in `T` (e.g., `Pick<A | B | C, K>` is *not* equivalent to `Pick<A, K> | Pick<B, K> | Pick<C, K>`.  If you want a distributive pick you can create one with a use a distributive conditional type as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9Oq9W).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think it's okay. Please, wrap that up in an answer, which is pretty useful (at least to me)! thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) doesn't *distribute* across [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`.  That means `Pick<A | B | C, K>` is *not* equivalent to `Pick<A, K> | Pick<B, K> | Pick<C, K>`.  TypeScript is working as intended here, according to [microsoft/TypeScript#28339](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28339), mostly because ([according to the TS team dev lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28339#issuecomment-478781328)) sometimes people don't want similar constructions to distribute across unions and because it's too late to change it now.

So if you `Pick<T, K>` when `T` is a union, you'll get a single object type where each property has become a union.

```
type A = { x: 1, y: 2 } | { x: true, y: false } | { x: "yes", y: "no" };
type PickAx = Pick<A, "x">;
// type PickAx = { x: true | 1 | "yes"; }
```

If you want distributive behavior from `Pick` you can write your own version.  [The current definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c56778871252c2f50058891c89c6d3253265fe36/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1571-L1576) is

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: T[P]; };
```

So we can wrap it in a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to make it distributive:

```
type DistribPick<T, K extends keyof T> =
  T extends unknown ? { [P in K]: T[P] } : never
```

(That `T extends unknown ? ⋯ : never` might look like it doesn't do anything, but because `T` is a generic type parameter, that causes the operation inside `⋯` to be distributed across unions in `T`).  If we try that we get:

```
type DistribPickAx = DistribPick<A, "x">
//  type DistribPickAx = { x: 1; } | { x: true; } | { x: "yes"; }
```

which is probably what you wanted.

---

On your example it becomes:

```
type TProvaBool = DistribPick<TProva<boolean>, "value" | "name" | "handler">;
/* type TProvaBool = {
    value?: boolean | undefined;
    name?: undefined;
    handler?: ((args: THandlerArgsUnnamed<boolean>) => void) | undefined;
} | {
    value?: boolean | undefined;
    name: string;
    handler?: ((args: THandlerArgsNamed<boolean>) => void) | undefined;
} */
```

and your compilation errors disappear:

```
function prova_bool(props: TProvaBool): void {
  const {
    value,
    name,
    handler,
  } = props;

  if (handler) {
    typeof name === "string"
      ? handler({ name, value }) // ok
      : handler({ name, value }) // ok
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4&ssl=99&ssc=39&pln=98&pc=39&filetype=ts#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgEgQwHYBMA2EBOBBTBzAZwCEECIAeGANQTQFcIA+KAXigG8AoKKAN1oYAuWDXrQAPlDqoIAMwCWSCCgDcnAL6dOoSLESoMOfAQCqSJAgC2yyqIbM28ZOiy5CJMrYFMoAMg7cUBbWwtIocorKapra4NBOBq7GAHJWNtTeDnrOhm7EpBQZYsz+XDzBEMIEwJiKeNFaWjrxAAqYAPb8HoV2PmxlfN4A-MJFDFCSYRFKqoGy7e0jUNW1SPWBAEZoCAAWS0h0lhtYDbG6MG2dCGYVKF7FrLCXXQX39n4B5WlLUwozajwdjksEsABQIYyjfQuIyEG5pO5jJgASlYzF47XksxizSeHX4qWsiN6WQu+IQ3TePlKgQqVRqdQBUCBiUwYIhhChwNhBEJ6RJqJY6Mx2KacTxVypDkCkjJV3hRKlMolBIRSp4ai0AHotXgIEpagBjKDySxgDDWJDABDAeTtJCcWTSQ22+1QMDkqWgj3tMAEUbPBBS5HCDFYz5QQ326oRnj8MQAGkCX2sSZ4gO5aag6kePr9mp48lkUFBLJhqIGPGa7WLFVYLDYACIVnVG8n00NmdzQewgmkE4MxNnke2eMIy4Ye33U4PxuoRzxNDFODq6AQEHrOD7+OQDkcsIwe7S0sJGwAPEAAL0bWYnWGEU4qA-jc8FwvDAAYB1AdXX5ARlgZNZhCjTBMAgF0AEINBHLdPT3Y5MEPAY70wB9eyfWdoHnNE+BFKAvx4X80hNADfkiFAQPaMCIOAaD50aHUCEgQ15FoeRLxtO0HTFXRsEeXsz2EABGAcQGEAAmbMJg4KAhKgGoGDE4RZFoMhpMkQTTxACACBvKBxKgRskHaRtszUXEWnkQ0AGtsDPR4rNs8hsAHc9G0YNQdQU8UnLshz+jk4RFIkKBhJkxsdL0lRszOaAABF-wZDY-Psx5EpbFLrJsly3LPDyVy1KtxQy5LUoC2T5OEmKc00oKFMwBgapkrSjKixsat4hKktqLLnJgAcAGkoAgM9gH1FAAJsiAQBrWBpR4GARrGiayKQGyTIAdyQKBO17ABtFoTR2waAF1RkO07pOEJReCwLqVQpBY0HSnr5D6nK5R3DZnogZBGDcl8IDMyRjLSEGjNQjyvIAKh885AyIZ6BPbIGlh+9oMGQGTyP+dsKh+GQ-iidtULBcFIWyVk8gVGwMaxpBGDfPCsVRSYiYo6IWtR4ZhHpv6dvZ8JidmdNp0qQDVnWMWyYfCnOSpmE8j5O5+f+5mwxQNmpA5vGcxhrVGkdZ1XR27cEAAfXp70Oj9ANySRzGQxZlAIyjJAY0rLCsxTCAfa7VksxzNg8wIAsTWLUtuQrdtq1rEiGybFs1jbMWeE7VDH37LDhx-Ir2hs0coHHbsMOzoHc+8gvAiXIA)